# How to update an attribute in object based on a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to update an attribute of an object but the attribute is not known before hand and is rather stored in a variable.
I have an object "obj" like below

```
 var obj={ a : 1, b : 2 }
```

if I want to change attribute "**a**" to 3 then I can just do
`obj.a = 3`
but I have a variable "*attribute_to_change*" which has the attribute that I want to change. I want to be able to somehow use the variable value to change the respective object attribute.
Something like below

```
obj.attribute_to_change = 3
```

Currently I have to write a separate line code of for each type of attribute that I want to change. But I can actually just make one function and pass the value and the attribute to be changed if I figure this out.

Comment: `obj[attribute_to_change] = 3`

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `const updateObject = (obj, key, newValue) => ({ ...obj, [key]: newValue })` which you can then invoke like so: `updateObject(myObject, 'attributeToChange', 3)`